# How to tangle single SRC block into multiple output files?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, python

I want to something like following to work:

```
#+begin_src python :tangle file1.py file2.py
import time
#+end_src
```

And after `tangling`, I want both `file1.py`, `file2.py` has lines.

How tangle single SRC block into multiple output files?

I found same [question 4 years ago](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/39032/tangle-the-same-src-block-to-different-files). But seems didn't work perhaps the versions aren't same as my emacs & org-version.

Is there any other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a global (or regional) `:prologue` that inserts common text at the front of blocks, `:epilogue` that inserts common text at the end of blocks, or use the more verbose `<<noweb>>` references to insert common text in the middle.

Not as elegant as the linked answer, but for small use cases, this could be manageable:

Common block

```
#+NAME: common
#+BEGIN_SRC code
common
#+END_SRC
```

File foo:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC code :tangle foo.file
<<<common>>>
foo
#+END_SRC
```

File bar:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC code :tangle bar.file
<<<common>>>
bar
#+END_SRC
```